# Assigning value to variable using if statement

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a learner. When I try to assign value to a variable as follows it doesn't work. Want to know the reason.

this doesn't work:

```
const w =
  if (2 > 1) {
    return 1500;
  } else {
    return 2500;
  }
```

However this works:

```
const w = function() {
  if (2 > 1) {
    return 1500;
  } else {
    return 2500;
  }
}()
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: First, you can't assign statements to any variable or constant in your case. Secondly, `return` keyword is used to return a value from a function not to assign a value to some other variable or constant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot use a statement to assign into a variable. For the alternate solution use conditional/Ternary operator

***Syntax***

const var_name = condition ? true_value : false_value

***Example***

```
const w = 2 > 1 ? 1500 : 2500
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript we use `if` in statements (that's why it's called *if statement*). However, what you have after `const w =` is an expression. Because of that, your first snippet didn't work: you cannot use `if` where JavaScript expects an expression.

That being said, you should use the *"analog"* of `if` for expressions, which is the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

In your case:

```js
const w = 2 > 1 ? 1500 : 2500;
console.log(w)
```

Alternatively, if you (for whatever reason) want to keep the `if` statement:

```js
let w;

if (2 > 1) {
  w = 1500
} else {
  w = 2500
};

console.log(w)
```